# pattern recognition 1d data

Tags: python, algorithm, pattern-recognition

I want to find pattern in some spectra. 
[Spectrum image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iu7m.png)

Pattern should look like 2 in gray circles on picture, all data looks similarly. Light blue line is the original data, dotted dark blue line - average over 6 points. I was trying to do window with some size and scan data and check whether the y-flux value drops/rise below 60 ish % but that seems to find other regions and the one that I want, or only this I don't want.

The width of pattern is not always the same in spectra that I have. There is a picture of spectrum with pattern black dashed line but my program didn't found it.

[not found picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCJit.png)

I tried changing size of window but it doesn't help. Can I use some pattern recognition algorithm to find this patterns? Could somebody point me in some direction? Or explain in easy way since I'm kinda lost in this, please?

That's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import ascii
import glob

def reading(file_name):
    data = ascii.read(file_name)
    lam = data['col0'][1:-1]
    #data offset *10**17 + 5
    flux = data['col1'][1:-1]*10**17 + 5

    return lam, flux

def percentChange(startPoint,currentPoint):

    return abs(((currentPoint-startPoint)/startPoint))*100.00

def window(data, size):   
    n = len(data)
    out = []   
    wind = data[0 : size]
    i = size    

    while i + size/2 < n:
        wind = data[i - size/2 : i + size/2]
        tmp = percentChange(wind[0], wind[-1])

        if tmp > 50.:
            out.append([tmp, i - size/2, i + size/2])
        i = i + size

    return out

def window2(data, size):

    n = len(data)
    out = []   
    wind = data[0 : size]
    i = size    

    while i + size/2 < n:
        wind = data[i - size/2 : i + size/2]
        tmp = percentChange(wind[0], wind[len(wind)/2])

        if tmp > 50.:
            out.append([tmp, i - size/2, i + size/2])
        i = i + size

    return out

def plotting(lamb, flux):
    plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'freeserif'
    plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 12
    plt.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 15
    plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 12
    plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 12
    plt.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 12
    plt.rcParams['figure.titlesize'] = 12 
    plt.rcParams['xtick.minor.visible'] = True
    plt.rcParams['ytick.minor.visible'] = True

    plt.plot(lamb, flux)
    plt.xlabel("wavelenght [A]")
    plt.ylabel("flux [erg/cm^2/s/A]")

def averaging(lamb, flux, param):
    end = 1480
    bin_flux_1 = [np.mean(flux[i : i + param]) for i in range(0, end, param)]
    bin_lam_1 = [np.mean(lamb[i : i + param]) for i in range(0, end, param)]

    return bin_lam_1, bin_flux_1


def main():

    param = 6
    stack = 6

    for name in glob.glob('TRAIN/*.dat'):
        print name
        lamb, flux = reading(name)
        lamb_a, flux_a = averaging(lamb, flux, param)

        plotting(lamb, flux)
        plotting(lamb_a, flux_a)

        change = window(flux_a, stack)
        change2 = window2(flux_a, stack)

        minim = flux_a.index(min(flux_a))

        for i in range(len(change)):
            plt.axvline(lamb_a[change[i][1]], color='r', linestyle='--',linewidth=1)
            plt.axvline(lamb_a[change[i][2]], color='r', linestyle='--',linewidth=1)
        for i in range(len(change2)):
            plt.axvline(lamb_a[change2[i][1]], color='y', linestyle='-',linewidth=1)
            plt.axvline(lamb_a[change2[i][2]], color='y', linestyle='-',linewidth=1)
        plt.axvline(lamb_a[minim], color='k', linestyle='--',linewidth=1)
        plt.show()    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm in linear `O(n + m)` time complexity where `n` and `m` are the lengths of text and pattern.

KMP algorithm is basically a pattern matching algorithm (finding the starting position of a needle in haystack) which works on character string.

```
def kmp_matcher(t, d):
    n=len(t)
    m=len(d)

    pi = compute_prefix_function(d)
    q = 0
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        if d[q]==t[i]:
            q=q+1
            i = i + 1
        else:
            if q != 0:
                q = pi[q-1]
            else:
                i = i + 1
        if q == m:
            print "pattern occurs with shift "+str(i-q)
            q = pi[q-1]

def compute_prefix_function(p):
    m=len(p)
    pi =range(m)
    k=1
    l = 0
    while k < m:
        if p[k] <= p[l]:
            l = l + 1
            pi[k] = l
            k = k + 1
        else:
            if l != 0:
                l = pi[l-1]
            else:
                pi[k] = 0
                k = k + 1
    return pi

t = 'brownfoxlazydog'
p = 'lazy'
kmp_matcher(t, p)
```

Comment: Okay, thank you, I will try it. I should find few patterns save them and then look in other spectra, but I'm a little worry about this liner time complexity, it is going to work if my patterns have such different y-values? I mean minimum point of my pattern can be -5 or 0? Or since I have so long "text" it will handle that?

Comment: KMP is for finding an exact match of a pattern.. You want to find a place where the running average drops below some threshold T for some width W.